# Debug and Release mode, must a rebuild be made for it to change?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm got a project that is on our production server that is published in Release mode. Now I'm getting a error on the production server I cant reproduce on our test server. My thought was to remote **debug** it when the error occur, which brings me to my question. Do I need to republish my project in **debug** mode or is it enough with changing the debug setting in **web.config**?

And if I have to republish in **debug** (which I probably have), does it affect performance a lot to have it in debug mode on production server for a while? whats you recommendations

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to republish with code in debug mode, for two reasons:

- The code compiled in debug mode contains some extra instructions that makes it possible to single step through the code, and the compiler is kept from rearranging the code so that it follows the order in the source code.
- The code compiled in debug mode contains extra information about the identifiers in the code.

There is a difference in performance between code in release mode and debug mode, but it's normally not that much. The main differences is that exceptions contains a lot more information, so they take a lot longer to create, and the scope of variables are larger, so unused objects may live longer before they are garbage collected.